# Persistence of planar trajectory converging to a node / focus

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, limits-and-convergence, manifolds

I consider a planar system $\dot u =F(u,p)$ where p is a scalar parameter. Suppose that the flow $\phi^t(u_0; 0)$ from $u_0$ converges to a stable node / focus $x^{eq}_0$ for the parameter value $p=0$.

By the implicit functions theorem, the node / focus equilibrium persists $x^{eq}_p$ for $p$ small. Is it true then that the flow $\phi^t(u_0; p)$ from $u_0$ for the small enough parameter value $p$ converges to $x^{eq}_p$?

Thank you a lot,

Bests

Comment: Yes because the basin of attraction should be smooth in 2D autonomous systems

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?